# Is a CEK machine an implementation of a CESK machine?

Tags: lambda-calculus

We know that a CESK machine [can be defined as](http://matt.might.net/articles/cesk-machines/):

> a state-machine in which each state has four components: a (C)ontrol component, an (E)nvironment, a (S)tore and a (K)ontinuation. One might imagine these respectively as the instruction pointer, the local variables, the heap and the stack.

Ed Kmett [writes](https://twitter.com/kmett/status/1021095147902316544?cn=ZmxleGlibGVfcmVjc18y&refsrc=email)

> Video from my recent twitch stream on CEK machines is up!

Matt Might [writes](http://matt.might.net/articles/cek-machines/):

> Writing CEK-style interpreters (or semantics) in Haskell

To Matt's credit - he also writes about CESK machines in [racket](http://matt.might.net/articles/cesk-machines/) and [Java](http://matt.might.net/articles/oo-cesk/).

But when we read the [original paper](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/ftp/techreports/TR202.pdf) ("A Calculus for Assignments in Higher Order Languages") by [Matthias Felleisen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthias_Felleisen) and [Dan Friedman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_P._Friedman) - we find that the original paper describes a CESK machine.

The paper also describes a CS machine - but not a CEK machine. The point being the Continuation and the Store are essential, but the Environment and the Continuation are negotiable.

My question is: **Is a CEK machine an implementation of a CESK machine?** (ie isn't the Store Essential?)

Comment: "The point being the Continuation and the Store are essential" seems to be "The point being the Control and the Store are essential"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The store in a CESK machine is the “heap”, where mutable pointer-based data structures live.

1. If your language is purely functional, then its operational  semantics don’t need a store. Take it out, and you get the CEK machine.
2. If your language does not have control operators (such as `call/cc` or exceptions), then you can get away without the K (the continuation).
3. If you don’t want to model environments and closures explicitly – that is, you don’t mind a substitution-based semantics – then you don’t need the E (the environment). Calculi for classical logic (which have control operators but no state) often end up looking like CK machines.
4. If you have a purely functional language without control effects, then you can use the program itself as the abstract machine state, and the reduction rules will be the small-step operational semantics for that language.